# Connection of Karov to Tefillah

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, tehilim-psalms, commentaries

A number of commentaries on the siddur (Rabbeinu Yehuda Ben Yakar, Avudarham, and some others) explain in the 5th blessing of the amida ("וקרבנו מלכנו לעבודתך") that עבודתך refers to Tefillah, and that קרבנו is used with reference to Tefillah.  To prove the latter point, they quote the following:

> ושייך קריבה בתפילה על שם אשר תבחר ותקרב (תהילים סה) ויש כאן בחירה וקריבה

Roughly translated: And closeness is related to prayer, as per the verse "Praiseworthy is the one whom You choose and bring close" and we have choosing and coming close.

How is Tefillah referenced in that verse from Tehillim?  Even out of context, I don't see what the inference is.